# Что означает "?" в дженериках?

Tags: java, классы, рефлексия

Изучаю сейчас Reflection. В примере есть строка

```
Class<?> cls1 = Integer.class;
```

Что означает знак вопроса?
И почему нельзя просто написать

```
Class cls1 = Integer.class;
```

Comment: он означает _любой класс_

Comment: А какой смысл он несет в данном контексте? Class - это уже как я понимаю тип переменной cls1. Зачем здесь дженерик?

Comment: Без `<?>` - это устаревший синтаксис и просто дурной тон.

Answer (score 4):

Grundy прав.
По идее он может быть полезен в трех случаях.

1. Когда классов обобщения несколько и лишь один нужно оставить неизвестным.
2. Когда вам необходимо одну и ту же переменную инициализировать объектами с разными видами обобщения. Если использовать `Object` то при инициализации `new List<Integer>` будет ошибка, а при `<?>` вы сможете инициализировать эту переменную и как `new List<Integer>` и как `new List<String>`.
3. Исходя из предыдущего, вы можете определять ее каким-либо интерфейсом или суперклассом `<? super Object>`, `<? extends Numeric>` и инициализировать любым классом, который подходит этим критериям, а не только конкретно этим интерфейсом или классом (Этакая двойная фильтрация).